# AS3 hitTestObject not registering correctly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I want to hit my target 3 times by clicking the attackButton and by using the hitTestObject, its life will also decrease from 3 to 0, and then after hitting my target and if the life is 0, it will go to the Congratulations screen or keyframe. My problem is that, it only registers the first time I hit the target, and then nothing happens after I hit it for the second, third time... and so on. Please help?

```
    var life = 3;

    attackButton.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, attack01);

    function attack01 (e:MouseEvent): void {
        colliderPlayer.gotoAndPlay(2);
    } 

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, lifeEnemy);

    function lifeEnemy(evt:Event): void {
        if(this.colliderPlayer.hitTestObject(boss)){
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, lifeEnemy);
            life = life - 1;
            trace(lifeEnemy);

            if(lifeEnemy==0) {
                MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop('ending');
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Replace `trace(lifeEnemy);` with `trace(life);` Now each time you click the attack button what's the output?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the hit test ceases to function is because if the hit test is successful you are removing the listener to check for the hit test the next time around.  The line I am referring to is:

```
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, lifeEnemy);
```

If you want to stop checking for hit's when the enemy's life is 0, do this:

```
var life = 3;

attackButton.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, attack01);

function attack01 (e:MouseEvent): void {
    colliderPlayer.gotoAndPlay(2);
} 

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, lifeEnemy);

function lifeEnemy(evt:Event): void {
    if(this.colliderPlayer.hitTestObject(boss)){
        life = life - 1;
        trace(life);

        if(life==0) {
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, lifeEnemy);
            MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop('ending');
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: it has error. It immediately went to the ending scene the first time I hit the target. I want it in the 3rd time.

I got this error in the output too:
`TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Plate2_fla::gamePlay2_444/lifePlayer1()`

Comment: After reviewing your code again I noticed a problem. I've corrected the `if` conditional.  Try it again.

Comment: Oh, yeah I've corrected that one already, but it's the same problem. It immediately goes to the ending scene the first time I hit the target, not allowing me the 2nd and 3rd time.

Comment: Have you debugged your code? If you debug it you can step through your code to see what exactly is happening. For all we know it could be that your `life` variable isn't set to a correct value.  It's hard for us to debug your code when we've only seen a small portion of it.

Comment: And to add, if you look at the error message, it's complaining about a function named `lifePlayer1()` which is a function that isn't shown in the code you posted.

Comment: Oh sorry, actually it's the same thing I've done with the player, the target also shoots something to the player, I have a jump button, wherein it'll dodge the object of the enemy. It's the same problem, it immediately goes to the Game Over scene if it collides with that object, even if I have 3 lives :(

Comment: What do the trace statements look like? Does it skip from 3 to 0, or do they count down like 3, 2, 1, 0? Again, debugging your code is the best way to analyze what is happening during the sequence of events within your application, which we cannot do since we don't know how your entire project is structured. The problem you speak of sounds like an unrelated issue to the one you have originally listed.